# Using $_GET method with forms PHP without changing url?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, get

```
http://example.com/bills.php?sort=highest 
http://example.com/bills.php?sort=alpha
http://example.com/bills.php?sort=lowest
```

So the urls aboves sort by highest, alphabetical and lowest. They use the $_GET method with the use of a form. I was wondering if there was a way to submit the form/get the $_GET data without changing the url?

```
<form action="bills.php" method="get">
    <select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="sort" class="right sort">
        <option>What would you like to sort by?</option>
        <option value="highest" <?php if(isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'highest'){?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Highest to Lowest</option>
        <option value="lowest" <?php if(isset($_GET['sort'])&& $_GET['sort'] == 'lowest'){?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Lowest to Highest</option>
        <option value="alpha" <?php if(isset($_GET['sort'])&& $_GET['sort'] == 'alpha'){?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Alphabetically</option>
    </select> 
</form>
```

Above is the code in which I am able to submit a new sort request.

I would like to make my url stay at `example.com/bills.php` would that be possible?

Would this be possible rewriting the url using .htaccess? I have tried a URL rewriting method which allows me to visit `http://example.com/bills/alpha` and it works fine, but when I select a new query, it turns into `http://example.com/bills/bills/?sort=alpha`.

Here's my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bills/(.*)$ /bills.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Use form method as post and keep the values in a hidden field under the same form

Comment: Is there any reason you're *not* using post?

Comment: I wanted to have the ability to be able to make a query with the use of variables also by typing it in. I was just wondering if there was any way to to use $_GET and have the url revert to bills.php after the query was done. If not I would like to find out how I could take an alternative and use URL rewriting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using AJAX, you can solve this problem. No need to do any changes in .htaccess. Here is the code which can helps you :

```
 $(".right").change(function(){
    $.get("YourFile.php",{"sort":$(this).val()},function(res){
       alert(res);
   });
});
```